# Prevent my own app's share extension from appearing in the share sheet

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, ios-sharesheet

I'm building an iOS app that manages audio files.  It includes a share extension to receive audio files from other apps.  It also can share its audio files with other apps.

When a share is initiated from my app, I do not want my own app to appear in the share sheet.  In other words, I do not want the user to send my own audio file back to my app.

I cannot find a way to exclude my own app with an NSExtensionActivationRule.

Comment: If you find the answer let me know !

Comment: Steve, what did you find out about this?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, we never found a way to solve this one.

Comment: @thibautnoah Did you get any answer ?

Comment: @ilesh unfortunatly no

Answer (score 1):

First of all define below lines in your code:

```
class ActionExtensionBlockerItem: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, dataTypeIdentifierForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
        return "com.your.unique.uti";
    }
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType) -> Any? {
        // Returning an NSObject here is safest, because otherwise it is possible for the activity item to actually be shared!
        return NSObject()
    }
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> String {
        return ""
    }
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, thumbnailImageForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?, suggestedSize size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return nil
    }
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Here `com.your.unique.uti` is your Application group identifier:

[image: see this image for refrence]

and then while presenting activityViewController use code below:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [/* Other Items To Share, */ ActionExtensionBlockerItem()], applicationActivities: nil)
```